# Matlab - Bar chart with two plots and two axis

Tags: matlab, bar-chart, matlab-figure, axis-labels

I am plotting two arrays in one plot. The bar plot must show two y-axis as well as the bars next to each other. The problem occurs when I want to implement both requirements.

I can either plot the bars together with for example

```
Y = [5,2; 8,7; 9,8; 5,5; 4,3];
figure
bar(Y)
```

Or I can create two y-axis (which I do currently with my data):

```
y = [lr_flights2018, lr_income2018]; 
yyaxis left
b = bar(1:length(y),lr_flights2018);
ylabel('Life Rating/flights ratio')
yyaxis right
p = bar(1:length(y),lr_income2018);
ylabel('Life Rating/income ratio')
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:length(y))
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{countries{:,1}})
xtickangle(90)
title('Correlations with life rating');
```

In the latter `yyaxis` separates the plots which results in the [two plots stacked together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpnRc.jpg). I want the plots to stand side by side for each bin as can be seen in 
[this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk9Cj.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by manipulating the x position and the bar width

I manipulated your Y data as shown below, and made some new labels for the countries which you didn't provide in your example

```
figure;
Y = [5,2; 8,7; 9,8; 5,5; 4,3];;
lr_flights2018 = Y(:,1);
lr_income2018 = Y(:,2);
y = [lr_flights2018, lr_income2018]; 
yyaxis left
b = bar((1:length(y))+0.125,lr_flights2018, 'barwidth', 0.25);
ylabel('Life Rating/flights ratio')
yyaxis right
p = bar((1:length(y))-0.125,lr_income2018, 'barwidth', 0.25);
ylabel('Life Rating/income ratio')
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:length(y))
str = strread ( sprintf ( '%i\n', [1:5] ), '%s', 'delimiter', '\n' )
set(gca,'XTickLabel',str)
xtickangle(90)
title('Correlations with life rating');
```

[image: example output from r2018b]